# Fade background colour depending on value JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I have a div. I want the background colour of the div to change depending on a value. The value is the temperature of a room in celsius.
If the value is less than 18 I want the colour to be blue. 
If its greater than 23 I want the colour to be red.
If its inbetween 18 and 23 I want the colour to fade between blue and red.
If its 20.5 I dont want the colour to be purple.
I want it to fade from blue to white to red if that makes sense.
Or blue to green to red (but the green to red fade could be a weird colour).
I was thinking of using javascript/jquery to achieve this but dont know how to go about it and couldnt find anything on here that was similar.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could calculate an opacity percentage from the temperature versus its change range...

I've made an automated demo (with an interval) to spare the clicking on the `input`...

```js
$("#tempSelect").on("change",function(){
  var temp = parseFloat( $(this).val() );

  if(temp<18){
    opacity = 1;
    color="rgba(40,40,255,"+opacity+")";
  }

  else if(temp>18 && temp<20.5){
    opacity = 1-(temp-18)/2.5;
    color="rgba(40,40,255,"+opacity+")";
  }

  else if(temp>20.5 && temp<23){
    opacity = (temp-20.5)/2.5;
    color="rgba(255,40,40,"+opacity+")";
  }
  
  else if(temp>23){
    opacity = 1;
    color="rgba(255,40,40,"+opacity+")";
  }

  console.log(color);
  $("#tempDisplay").html(temp+"&deg;C").css({"background-color":color});
});

// On load, set a color.
$("#tempSelect").trigger("change");


// Just for the demo...

setInterval(function(){
  var tempInput = parseFloat($("#tempSelect").val())+0.1;
  $("#tempSelect").val(tempInput.toFixed(1)).trigger("change");
  if(parseFloat($("#tempSelect").val())>24){
    $("#tempSelect").val(17);
  }
},500);
```

```css
#tempSelect{
  width:6em;
}
#tempDisplay{
  width:4.5em;
  margin-top:4px;
  padding:6px;
  font-weight:bold;
  background-color:rgba(40,40,255,1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="tempSelect" type="number" step=0.1 value=17>
<div id="tempDisplay">0&deg;C</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [HSL](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp) instead of [RGB](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_rgb.asp) to represent your colors.

Changing the `hue` component you can fade from one color to another (if you want to have that blue-green-red schame).

Otherwise, you can use the `lightness` component to fade from one color to white and then from white to another color, like so:

```js
const body = document.body;

document.getElementById('temperature').oninput = (e) => {

  const t = e.target.value;
  
  let hue;
  let lightness = 50;
  
  if (t < 18) {
    // If the value is less than 18,
    // I want the colour to be blue:
    
    hue = 200;
  } else if (t > 23) {
    // If its greater than 23,
    // I want the colour to be red:
    
    hue = 0;
  } else if (t < 20.5) {
    // Value in range [18, 20.5).
    // Should fade from blue to white:
    
    hue = 200;
    lightness = 50 + 50 * (t - 18) / 2.5;
  } else {
    // Value in range (20.5, 23].
    // Should fade from white to red:
    
    hue = 0;
    lightness = 50 + 50 * (23 - t) / 2.5;
  }

  body.style.background = `hsl(${ hue }, 100%, ${ lightness }%)`;
};
```

```html
<input type="number" id="temperature" step="0.1" value="18"/>
```

Note you can achieve this same thing using `RGB`, just by keeping the red or blue component fixed and rising the other two to fade the color to white. However, I find it way easier to fade/mix colours, in general, using `HSL`.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a simple example which might help you to start. In the example you can change the current temperature via 2 buttons. The colors are changed with the animate() method which will change the backgroundColor attribute. [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/flosommerfeld/9RUBR/16/) for a jsfiddle.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div style="height:100px;width:300px;margin-bottom: 1em;background-color:white;"></div>
  <button id="plus" onclick="plusOneTemp()">
    Plus 1 degree celsius
  </button>
  <button id="minus" onclick="minusOneTemp()">
    Minus 1 degree celsius
  </button>
  <p>
    Value:
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

```
    var speed = 1000;
    var delay = 0;
    var temp = 25;


    function checkTemp() {
      if (temp < 18) { //change to blue
        $("div")
          .delay(delay)
          .animate({
            backgroundColor: "#64b5f6"
          }, speed);
      } else if (temp >= 18 && temp <= 23) { //change to orange
        $("div")
          .delay(delay)
          .animate({
            backgroundColor: "#ffb74d"
          }, speed);
      } else if (temp > 23) { //change to red
        $("div")
          .delay(delay)
          .animate({
            backgroundColor: "#ef5350"
          }, speed);
      }
    }
    $("#plus").click(function() {
      temp += 1;
      $("p").text("Value: " + temp);
      checkTemp();
    });
    $("#minus").click(function() {
      temp -= 1;
      $("p").text("Value: " + temp);
      checkTemp();
    });


    $("p").text("Value: " + temp);
    checkTemp();
```